# I am getting an error GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Well, there are lots of questions in StackOverflow about this error I've seen all of them none of them is working for me.
I'm using react with redux trying to fetch some products. my backend server node is running on port 5000 and I'm using concurrently to start both servers at the same time whenever I'm trying fetch the data its using port 3000 where is my frontend running. Please somebody help me to solve this issue

### package.json file

```
{
  "name": "proshop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MERN application named proshop",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "NodeJS",
    "ExpressJs",
    "React",
    "Redux",
    "MongoDb"
  ],
  "author": "Narayan Maity",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

### Here is my productsAction.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products');

    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

### If I use the full address like HTTP://localhost:5000/api/products its giving me CORS error

Comment: in `react` or `client` folder, add new `key` and `value` pair of `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in your `package.json`. Then you can just do `await axios.get('/api/products')`

Comment: thanks @lala it worked plz post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much more easier and `focus` if you add `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in your `client` or `react` project folder, like so:-

#### client/package.json

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  ...}
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Then you can just do:-

```
await axios.get('/api/products') // straight away use whatever path you've specified
```

Comment: i ahve added proxy but getting the error and on browser this code appears
try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')

    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}

i have set my proxy to "proxy": "http://localhost:5000", but still getting error

Comment: **CORS** errors? or different error? Can you update your code above too

Comment: import axios from 'axios'
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
} from '../constants/productConstants'
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')
dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: the thing is when is throw error using below code :

import express from 'express'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import Product from '../models/productModel.js'

const router = express.Router()

//@desc     Fetch all Products
//@route    GET /api/products
//@access   Public

router.get(
  '/',
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({})
    throw new Error('Some Error')
    res.json(products)
  })
)

i get  error but when i remove the line it wroks fine
when it throws error it looks for data from :3000/api/products

Comment: can update & show the `JSX` part of the code where you display the `products` you've fetched.