# Spring Boot @CrossOrigin not working for React front-end (with authorization header)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, axios, cors

I am making a full stack web-application using a Spring Boot - Java back-end and a React front-end. I am running into a problem with cross origin. My React front-end is saying it is not allowed to perform cross-origin operations, while I did in fact specify that localhost:3000 should be allowed.

Pictures:

[image: The error in my browser]

[image: I do have @CrossOrigin for the right url on my controller]

The error appeared after I started working on basic security (authentication) in my backend and when i started sending an authorization header in my requests from the front-end. Perhaps there is a mistake in that code? See my authenticationconfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthenticationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                //.formLogin().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Or is there a mistake in my controller?

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/auth")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> authenticate() {
        //throw new RuntimeException("Some Error has Happened! Contact Support at ***-***");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("You are authenticated", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: My axios request:

```
axios.get(baseUrl + "auth",
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(document.getElementById("email") + ":" + document.getElementById("password"))
                }
            }
        ).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(window.btoa(document.getElementById("email") + ":" + document.getElementById("password")));
            if(result.data == "You are authenticated"){
                localStorage.setItem('creds', window.btoa(document.getElementById("email") + ":" + document.getElementById("password")));
                console.log("Credentials stored in local storage.");
                return <Redirect to='/'  />
            } else {
                window.alert(result.data)
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't if this will work with `Java`, but anyhow just have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64767422/i-am-getting-an-error-get-http-localhost3000-api-products-404-not-found?noredirect=1#comment114514829_64767422)

Comment: try to set @CrossOrigin("http://localhost") instead of "http://localhost:3000